# IF condition is not checked

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

```
$sql = " SELECT team FROM user_pokemon_db WHERE user_id = '".$id."' ";
$res  = mysql_query($sql);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $assgn_team = $rows['team'];
    if($assgn_team > 6)
    {
        //code
    }

     else
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

My 'team' column is consisting of integers: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
In my case, if the column 'team' is consisting of a number 6, then I want to execute the if block.
But its not checking the if condition and I directly jumping on to the else block.

I am sure, the problem is somewhere here:

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $assgn_team = $rows['team'];
}
```

Is the above logic right?? Its purpose is to check every record in the 'team' column.

Comment: If it contains 6, you should use `>=`

Comment: consider `$assgn_team == 6` instead of `$assgn_team > 6`

Answer (score 1):

You need to casting value string to int. Type casting make you allow to compare more then string. Try this:

```
$assgn_team = (int)$rows['team'];
if($assgn_team > 6)
{
    //code
}
```

`EDIT` or use:

```
$assgn_team = (int)$rows['team'];
if($assgn_team == 6)
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: Actually.. I want to store every value in an array! 
and then use IF() to find whether there is any '6' in the array...!
How should I do that

Comment: than make $assgn_team === 6 instead of $assgn_team > 6. I have update my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Make if condition as

**if($assgn_team >= 6) {
    ...
  }**

**i.e.**

```
$sql = " SELECT team FROM user_pokemon_db WHERE user_id = '".$id."' ";
$res  = mysql_query($sql);
$assgn_team = $rows['team'];
if($assgn_team >= 6) {
  //code
} else {
  //code
}
```